# entries inside entries in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am trying to create a small application for keeping track of expenses when ordering food
the tkinter i am using is something like this

i can add new person
under each person i can have a box for inputting the values 3 fields

- name
- quantity
- price

there has to be a window beside the user which shows the total value of order (per user)

then total bill has to displayed (on top or somewhere)

here is my tkinter code i have done so far

```py
import tkinter as tk

# Function to calculate the total for an item
def calculate_item_total(price, quantity):
    return price * quantity + 5

# Function to add a new person
def add_person():
    name = name_entry.get()
    person_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame)
    person_frame.pack()
    person_label = tk.Label(person_frame, text=name)
    person_label.pack()
    name_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    
    items = []
    
    def add_item():
        item_name = item_entry.get()
        price = float(price_entry.get())
        quantity = float(quantity_entry.get())
        total = calculate_item_total(price, quantity)
        items.append((item_name, price, quantity, total))
        update_items()
        item_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        price_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        quantity_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    
    def delete_person():
        person_frame.destroy()
    
    def delete_item(item_index):
        del items[item_index]
        update_items()
    
    def update_items():
        for widget in item_frame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        for i, (item_name, price, quantity, total) in enumerate(items):
            tk.Label(item_frame, text=item_name).grid(row=i, column=0)
            tk.Label(item_frame, text=price).grid(row=i, column=1)
            tk.Label(item_frame, text=quantity).grid(row=i, column=2)
            tk.Label(item_frame, text=f"Total: {total}").grid(row=i, column=3)
            tk.Button(item_frame, text="Delete", command=lambda i=i: delete_item(i)).grid(row=i, column=4)
    
    item_frame = tk.Frame(person_frame)
    item_frame.pack()
    
    tk.Label(item_frame, text="Item").grid(row=0, column=0)
    tk.Label(item_frame, text="Price").grid(row=0, column=1)
    tk.Label(item_frame, text="Quantity").grid(row=0, column=2)
    
    item_entry = tk.Entry(item_frame)
    item_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)
    price_entry = tk.Entry(item_frame)
    price_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
    quantity_entry = tk.Entry(item_frame)
    quantity_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)
    
    add_item_button = tk.Button(item_frame, text="Add Item", command=add_item)
    add_item_button.grid(row=2, columnspan=3)
    
    delete_person_button = tk.Button(person_frame, text="Delete Person", command=delete_person)
    delete_person_button.pack()

# main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Expense Tracker")

# main frame
main_frame = tk.Frame(root)
main_frame.pack()

# heading
heading_label = tk.Label(main_frame, text="Expense Tracker", font=("Helvetica", 16))
heading_label.pack()

# frame for adding people
add_person_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame)
add_person_frame.pack()
name_label = tk.Label(add_person_frame, text="Name:")
name_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
name_entry = tk.Entry(add_person_frame)
name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
add_button = tk.Button(add_person_frame, text="Add Person", command=add_person)
add_button.grid(row=0, column=2)


# Start the main loop
root.mainloop()
```

i am not able to add new  items and total value box also not getting rendered properly
when i try to add new item this is the error i am getting

```
╰─ python -u "/home/siddharth/vscode/otherprojects/menusplitter/billsplitter.py"
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/siddharth/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/siddharth/vscode/otherprojects/menusplitter/billsplitter.py", line 25, in add_item
    item_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
  File "/home/siddharth/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3039, in delete
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'delete', first, last)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!frame2.!frame.!entry"
```

i am new to tkinter if anyone knows how to fix it please help me out

Comment: The `update_items()` before the `item_entry.delete(0, tk.END)` might be destroying the entry because you destroy all of `item_frame.winfo_children()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error usually happens when you try to access a destroyed widget in `tkinter`.

In your case, the `add_item` function calls the `update_items` function which calls the destroy() method for each of the `Entry` widgets.

Than the function tries to delete the content of the already destroyed entries:

```
    def add_item():
        item_name = item_entry.get()
        price = float(price_entry.get())
        quantity = float(quantity_entry.get())
        total = calculate_item_total(price, quantity)
        items.append((item_name, price, quantity, total))

        update_items()# --> destroys all the widgets in item_frame, including the labels, the entries and the 'Add item' button
        # tries to delete the content of destroyed entries
        item_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        price_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        quantity_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
...

    def update_items():
        for widget in item_frame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy() # --> destroys all the widgets in item_frame, including the labels, the entries and the 'Add item' button
```

---

### **Edit**

You use your `update_item` function to configure the widgets in `item_frame` like so:

```py
def add_person():

    ...

    def update_items():
        for widget in item_frame.winfo_children():
            widget.grid_forget()
            
        tk.Label(item_frame, text="Item").grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Label(item_frame, text="Price").grid(row=0, column=1)
        tk.Label(item_frame, text="Quantity").grid(row=0, column=2)
        
        for i, (item_name, price, quantity, total) in enumerate(items):
            row_i = i + 1
            tk.Label(item_frame, text=item_name).grid(row=row_i, column=0)
            tk.Label(item_frame, text=price).grid(row=row_i, column=1)
            tk.Label(item_frame, text=quantity).grid(row=row_i, column=2)
            tk.Label(item_frame, text=f"Total: {total}").grid(row=row_i, column=3)
            tk.Button(item_frame, text="Delete", command=lambda i=i: delete_item(i)).grid(row=row_i, column=4)
        
        s_row = len(items) + 1
        item_entry.grid(row=s_row, column=0)
        price_entry.grid(row=s_row, column=1)
        quantity_entry.grid(row=s_row, column=2)
        add_item_button.grid(row=s_row + 1, columnspan=3)
          
    
    item_frame = tk.Frame(person_frame)
    item_frame.pack()
    
    item_entry = tk.Entry(item_frame)
    price_entry = tk.Entry(item_frame)
    quantity_entry = tk.Entry(item_frame)
    add_item_button = tk.Button(item_frame, text="Add Item", command=add_item)
    update_items()
    
    delete_person_button = tk.Button(person_frame, text="Delete Person", command=delete_person)
    delete_person_button.pack()
```

Comment: if possible can you give me solution to fix this issue ? like i am not able to find it even using chatgpt and i am not that good with tkinter ... thanks for helping me understand the issue btw

Comment: I don't know what you've tried to achieve by both deleting the widgets and clearing them.

Comment: will the thing is i wanted a app like sort of where i can add multiple people calculated the total prices of each item under per person

sort of looks like this 
```
- person
---- item 1
---- item 2 
```
so on  ... all i wanted was to add more people or delete people add more items and delete items and alter them

Comment: @Nugget please see the edit. Also, if my answer helped you please consider accepting it.

Comment: Thanks a lot omg !! finally its working thank you so much !!!!